# Terminology for a "relative" (or perhaps "local") density of a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, terminology

Consider the prime numbers and the Fibonacci numbers. Both of them have an asymptotic density of $0$. Yet we know that, in some sense, the set of primes is larger than the set of Fibonacci numbers; the primes are a large set, and the Fibonacci numbers are a small set.

And while the asymptotic density of these sets is $0$, we have asymptotic estimates for both. The Prime Number Theorem tells us that

$$\frac{\pi(x)}{x} \sim \frac{1}{\log x - 1}$$

and using $C_F(x)$ as a counting function for the Fibonacci numbers, in parallel with $\pi(x)$, we can easily show that

$$\frac{C_F(x)}{x} \sim \frac{\log x}{x \log \phi}$$

Taking the counting function and dividing by its argument sure seems like a "density" of some sort, even if at the limit of infinity, both of these formulas give us $0$. Is there a proper term for this?

---

**Edit**: the Wikipedia article on twin primes implies that these could be considered as probability density functions... but I'm entirely uncertain if that's justified. Thoughts?

Comment: I'd use the term, *thinner*. The Fibonacci sequence is thinner than the sequence of primes.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. So we could call these expressions the "thickness" of the set within $\mathbb{N}$, you think?

Comment: An interesting aside: whatever these are called, they're decoupled from the sums of reciprocals. This function for the squares is $\frac{1}{sqrt{x}}$; assuming the TPC, for the twin primes we have $\frac{2C_2}{(\log x)^2}$. Now $\frac{2C_2}{(\log x)^2} > \frac{1}{sqrt{x}} > \frac{2 \log x}{x}$. But the reciprocal sums are, respectively, $~1.92, ~1.6, ~3.35$. Interesting.